# GCP traffic splitting across external services in url map error: "One of backend_service or url_redirect must be set"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

First of all, I have an internet network endpoint group (NEG):

```
gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups update [neg-name] \
    --add-endpoint="fqdn=[service.example.com],port=443" \
    --global
```

This is what's called "Global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)" in the Backend Service documentation.

I have two services, created like this:

```
gcloud beta compute backend-services create [service-name] \
        --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
        --protocol=HTTPS \
        --port-name=https \
        --enable-logging \
        --logging-sample-rate=1 \
        --global

gcloud beta compute backend-services add-backend [service-name] \
       --network-endpoint-group=[neg-name] \
       --global-network-endpoint-group \
       --global \
       --custom-request-header="Host: service.example.com" # Fix SSL issue
```

I also have a url map, created like this:

```
gcloud beta compute url-maps create [url-map-name] \
        --default-service [service 1 name]
```

I want to create a traffic splitting rule that routes traffic between service 1 and service 2. Following the [load balancing docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-global-traffic-mgmt#split-traffic), I came up with this:

```yaml
creationTimestamp: '2021-11-26T12:41:59.779-08:00'
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[project-name]/global/backendServices/[service 1 name]
fingerprint: [fingerprint]
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - '*'
  pathMatcher: default-matcher
id: [id]
kind: compute#urlMap
name: [url-map-name]
pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[project-name]/global/backendServices/[service 1 name]
  name: default-matcher
  routeRules:
  - priority: 1
    matchRules:
      - prefixMatch: '/'
    routeAction:
      weightedBackendServices:
        - weight: 50
          backendService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[project-name]/global/backendServices/[service 2 name]
        - weight: 50
          backendService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[project-name]/global/backendServices/[service 1 name]
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[project-name]/global/urlMaps/[url-map-name]
```

When I try to edit the url map with the above configuration, the following error is returned (debugger breakpoints included in output):

```
$ gcloud beta compute url-maps edit [url-map-name] --global --verbosity=debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.beta.compute.url-maps.edit] with arguments: [--global: "True", --verbosity: "debug", URL_MAP: "[url-map-name]"]
INFO: Display format: "default"
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): compute.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/beta HTTP/1.1" 200 None
> /opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/url_maps/edit.py(100)_ProcessEditedResource()
-> return holder.client.MakeRequests(
(Pdb) c
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/beta HTTP/1.1" 200 None
> /opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/batch_helper.py(117)MakeRequests()
-> error_message = None
(Pdb) c
> /opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/client_adapter.py(116)MakeRequests()
-> utils.RaiseToolException(errors, error_message="Could not fetch resource:")
(Pdb) errors
[(400, 'Invalid value for field \'resource\': \'{  "name": "[url-map-name]",  "hostRule": [{    "host": ["*"],    "pathMatcher": "default-matcher...\'. One of backend_service or url_redirect must be set')]
(Pdb) c
There was a problem applying your changes: Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource': '{  "name": "[url-map-name]",  "hostRule": [{    "host": ["*"],    "pathMatcher": "default-matcher...'. One of backend_service or url_redirect must be
 set

Would you like to edit the resource again? (Y/n)?  n
```

Validating (Thank you Alex G):

```
$ gcloud beta compute url-maps validate --source=url-map-traffic-splitting.yml --global --verbosity=debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.beta.compute.url-maps.validate] with arguments: [--global: "True", --source: "url-map-traffic-splitting.yml", --verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): compute.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /compute/beta/projects/[project-name]/global/urlMaps/[url-map-name]/validate?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO: Display format: "default"
result:
  loadErrors:
  - One of backend_service or url_redirect must be set
  loadSucceeded: false
  testPassed: false
DEBUG: SDK update checks are disabled.
```

What I've tried:

- Tried with pathRules instead of routeRules, it works and the url map is updated.
- I tried hacking the gcloud libraries to give better errors - but the error is returned by the API, not the client:

  ```
  HttpError accessing <https://compute.googleapis.com/batch/compute/beta>: response: <{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'status': '400'}>, content <{
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource': '{  \"name\": \"[url-map-name]\",  \"hostRule\": [{    \"host\": [\"*\"],    \"pathMatcher\": \"default-matcher...'. One of backend_service or url_redirect must be set",
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource': '{  \"name\": \"[url-map-name]\",  \"hostRule\": [{    \"host\": [\"*\"],    \"pathMatcher\": \"default-matcher...'. One of backend_service or url_redirect must be set",
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "invalid"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ```
- I've searched the GCP documentation for any mentions of this error, or mentions of limits to what url maps can do, but found nothing.

Comment: Can you try adding `--verbosity=debug` in your command and add it to your post. Also, do you have a [validation test](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#validate_url_map)?  You can check that by using the command `gcloud compute url-maps describe <name>` to check.

Comment: @AlexG I didn't know about the validator, thank you! Found an error in one of my files, but the issue in the question is still the same. Added the info you asked for.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a need to add second defaultService section in the LB yaml config file because the default service is already defined before the pathMatcher. Can you try removing that?

Comment: @AlexG Thank you so much for looking into this. Without the second `defaultService`: `HTTPError 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.pathMatchers[0].defaultService': ''. No default backend service specified for path matcher`.

Comment: I just confirmed that the split traffic feature is not available for non classic Global LB but a possible workaround would be a header based rule on the VM or rate limiting one of your server to a small number. It should have the same capabilities but won't be as smooth as split traffic feature. Just a disclaimer for the rate limit, it may cause 1 server to get a lot of traffic than the others until the rate is hit. Or better just use the new Global LB

Comment: @AlexG Thank you again for getting back to me.

I'm a bit confused about the terminology. Are you saying that the classic global LB would work? Or the new global LB? Could you point me in the right direction? :) I'm currently looking at [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) - but I think I had issues with both Envoy and Classic.

I'm open to using anything that supports traffic splitting + cloud armor + load balancing for external HTTPS backends.

Comment: I was in the same issue, classic LB throws that error whereas the new global LB works